# What does gen~ phasor() do? (Translating Max/MSP gen to C++)

Tags: c++, code-translation, max-msp-jitter

We have two places in the same gen~ code box object with phasor:

```
wander = phasor(in8/dense);

...some code later...

phas = (triangle(phasor(freq), sharp)*len-rot_x/(2*pi))%1;
```

I understand that `phasor()` produces a rising sawtooth, outputting values of 0 to 1. I understand the argument of `phasor()` is frequency. What I don't understand is how `phasor()` can output a value of 0 to 1 given frequency, when you would need frequency over time to produce a value other than 0. It would seem that `phasor(frequency)` should always output 0 unless somehow `phasor()` is keeping track of time and its own phase.

If phasor is keeping track of time/phase, how can we call `phasor()` twice in the same gen code box? It would seem impossible that we could have two time values. Unless...

...we have one time/phase value shared between all calls to `phasor()` but it is the last call to `phasor()` that sets the final frequency before `phasor()` increments its phase, which happens at the end of the code block.

Am I correct?

Edit: No that can't be, then why would you ever put a frequency into phasor twice? It wouldn't change the output under my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my tests, phasor is indeed a sawtooth oscillator object where each call to phasor is a unique oscillator, so, calling phasor twice in the same code box will instantiate two objects.

```
class Phasor
{
public:
    double getSample() 
    { 
        double ret = phase/PI_z_2;
        phase = fmod(phase+phase_inc, TAU); //increment phase
        return ret;
    }
    void setSampleRate(double v) { sampleRate = v; calculateIncrement(); }
    void setFrequency(double v) { frequency = v; calculateIncrement(); }
    void reset() { phase = 0.0; }
protected:
    void calculateIncrement() { phase_inc = TAU * frequency / sampleRate; }
    double sampleRate = 44100.0; 
    double frequency = 1.0;
    double phase = 0.0;
    double phase_inc = 0.0;
    const double TAU = 2*PI;
    const double PI_z_2 = PI/2.0;
};
```

Comment: Lovely class! Would you mind explaining what the PI_z_2 variable is please?

Comment: z means divide Pi divided by 2, just added it to the code